# how to check whether user are login in moodle?

Tags: authentication, moodle

Currently I'm using moodle to create a site.
I want to create a function if user not login they will redirect to the login page.
How can I do that in moodle?

Comment: serverfault?currently imade a category..when user not login it will say no course..i want it redirect to login page..

Answer (score 12):

**Assumption -** Writing a custom page in PhP, hosted on same server on moodle site.

Then the page will have access to the session information and the task is very straighforward.

First you call the moodle bootstap, then call the moodle function to check for a valid login.

```
require_once('../../config.php');  // specify path to moodle /config.php file

// require valid moodle login.  Will redirect to login page if not logged in.
require_login();

// if you also include the id number of a course then require permisision to view a particular course 
require_login(78);  // requires login and permission to view course id 78.
```

Answer (score 8):

Following code snippet might be of some help

```
require_once('/home/public-html/moodle/config.php'); 
if (!isloggedin()) {
    //redirect to moodle login page
} else {
    //do whatever you want here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, easily accessed via Settings > Site admin > Security > Site policies

Check 'Force users to log in'

Done :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `require_login();` function, you can decide whether or not to check user login.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it might be helpful to people who are new to Moodle! There is a function called `isloggedin()` (defined in lib/accesslib.php) that allows you to determine if a user is logged in or not.

Comment: Is that different from the `isloggedin()` that @iankit's answer mentions? If not, perhaps a comment on that answer is better than a seperate answer?